# Should SiteMesh capabilities be used in smaller Grails sites?

Tags: grails

Can you provide some architecture/design advice in regard to using SiteMesh capabilities versus partial templates or other gsp capabilities for smaller grails sites?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see why you *wouldn't* use Grails' built-in SiteMesh layouts for almost everything that deals with standard laying-out of pages (*especially* on smaller sites, where performance is probably a non-issue).

By not using it, you'd be working against what Grails is providing for you as a convenience.

Comment: Thanks, I had read it is primarily for larger sites.  So, from highest to lowest "granularity", it looks like the mechanism for modularizing page layout in Grails is: 1) SiteMesh, then 2) partial templates, then 3) custom tags.   I forgot to add the seeming highest: changing the templates that are used to build the default gsp pages.   Any thoughts/comments please add them.  Thanks.

Comment: I usually don't use the scaffolded templates. I make use of SiteMesh layouts on almost all of my apps, since it's built-in and already there to be used. I use templates when I need to render similar content on different views. I use custom tags the most: almost any time I find myself doing something that involves logic (and not just markup), I use a taglib. There's usually no good reason *not* to use all of the tools that Grails provides when the situation requires them.